find xyz coordinate inside 3d polygon
I am trying to find a way to get a point definitive inside a 3d polygon (planar)
currently I am trying to do that like this:
 let sumX = 0
      let sumY = 0
      let sumZ = 0
      const numPoints = area.boundary.length
      for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
        sumX += area.boundary[i].position[0]
        sumY += area.boundary[i].position[1]
        sumZ += area.boundary[i].position[2]
      }
      const areaPosition = [sumX / numPoints, sumY / numPoints, sumZ / numPoints]

the issue is, that if the polygon is not concave - I can get points which are not inside the polygon. is there any clever way to find a point inside the polygon? preferably in the "middle", not necessarily the centroid, because its also not guarantied to lay inside of the polygon.
any idea would be great!
thanks a lot!

What do you mean by a "point definitive?" And when you write "3d polygon (planar)", what do you mean by planar? If you're just looking for ANY point inside the polyhedron (the 3D figure), why not pick the XYZ midpoint of two random vertices? I don't know typescript, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

There are 2 different problems here: 1. work with a 3D planar polygon 2. Find a point inside a polygon, close to its "center".
I'll write the solution in C++ using glm (OpenGL Mathematics Library) but you may translate it to any language and 3d mathematics library
work with a 3D planar polygon
select any 3 non collinear v1,v2,v3 polygon points and find M that brings any v on the same plane to the XY plane (Z=0):
glm::vec3 u = v2-v1;
glm::vec3 v = v3-v1;
glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(u,v));
glm::vec3 v1 = glm::vec3(1, 0,0); // Arbitrary vector
glm::vec3 v2 = glm::cross(n, v1); // Ensure v2 is orthogonal to 'n'
v2 = glm::normalize(v2); // normalize v2 to ensure orthogonality

// Construct a matrix M with columns: v1, v2, n so that Mv transforms any vertex to XY
glm::mat4 M = glm::mat4(
    glm::vec4(v1, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(v2, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(n, 0.0f),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
);
glm::vec4 vz = M * glm::vec4(v1, 1.0f);
M[4][3] = -vz.z; // For any point on the plane M*p will have z=0

Now bring all your points to the XY plane:
std::vector<glm::vec2> toXY(const glm::mat4& M, const std::vector<glm::vec3>& polygonPoints) 
{
    std::vector<glm::vec2> transformed;
    for (const auto& p: polygonPoints) {
        glm::vec4 pt = M * glm::vec4(v1, 1.0f);
        transformed.emplace_back(pt.x, pt.y);
    }
    return transformed;
}

This means that after you solve the second problem and have glm::vec2 pInside you'll need to transform it back to the 3D polygon plane simply by:
glm::vec3 vInside = glm::inverse(M) * glm::vec4(pInside.x, pInside.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);

Find a point inside a polygon, close to its "center"

Find the center like you did: pCenter
Check "point within polygon" (there are many algorithms)
if inside then done. otherwise:
Find the closest edge to pCenter, defined by 2 points: pClosest and pClosestNext (more code to find)
Assuming a CW (clock wise) polygon, the index of pClosestNext is +1
to pClosest, otherwise (CCW polygon) it is -1 .

Call GetInside :
glm::vec2 GetInside(const glm::vec2& pCenter, const glm::vec2& pClosest, 
        const glm::vec2& pClosestNext, std::vector<glm::vec2> transformed) 
{
    glm::vec2 pOnEdge = (pClosest+pClosestNext)/2;
    glm::vec2 direction = glm::normalize(pOnEdge - pCenter);
    float L = glm::distance(pCenter, pOnEdge) / 100.0f;
    glm::vec2 pInside = pOnEdge + direction * L; // must be inside for L>0 small enough 
    while (!PointInPolygon(P, transformed))
        L = L /= 2.0f;
    return pInside;
}


If you know the polygon is simple and nondegenerate (that is, if you know it has no self-intersections), you can just find a convex corner of the polygon, take that position, and then mix in a little bit of the neighboring vertices to move it inside:

As d approaches 0, it becomes certain that the point hasn't strayed too far from its protective corner. The ideal value of d is infinitesimal.
Now, depending on the sorts of math you're doing, this may not be an acceptable form: if you're playing things fast and loose with floating point numbers and predicates you could easily make d so small that the sample becomes indistinguishable from the corner. The slightly more robust version of this is to make sure you pick a good convex corner, i.e. one which isn't too acute and which has the furthest distance to other boundary edges. At the other end of the robustness scale you want to find the center of the largest inscribed circle, which is discussed in this question.
